# PHP remove part of URL before querystring

Tags: php

I have url like this `http://example.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/Page.php?charts.htm` and I need to remove the page/extension before the querystring so it outputs `http://example.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/?charts.htm`

```
$url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$temp = explode( '?'  , $url );
$temp[0] = ""; //remove part before the ?
```

Not even sure if I'm on the right track here

Comment: you're kind of on the right track if you want the page to redirect to the url without Page.php in the name. if you want this done dynamically on each request without a redirect on page load, then you need to use .htaccess

Comment: This will be output on a page, not a redirect. Just need to show the new url with the Page.php removed

Comment: See [parse_url()](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
$url = str_replace("Page.php", "", $url);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `parse_url()` and `dirname()`

```
$url = "http://example.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/Page.php?charts.htm";
$urlArray = parse_url($url); // Array ( [scheme] => http [host] => example.com [path] => /dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/Page.php [query] => charts.htm )

$newURL  = $urlArray["scheme"]."://".$urlArray["host"]."/";
$newURL .= dirname($urlArray["path"])."/?".$urlArray["query"];
// gives http://example.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/?charts.htm
```